# Installing Lexmark X1290 printer on 64-bit Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: 64-bit, printing, ubuntu-10.10

I'm trying to install the Lexmark X1290 printer on a 64-bit Ubuntu 10.10 system. I previously had this printer working flawlessly on a 32-bit Ubuntu 10.04.

I'm following the instructions from [http://www.trodrigues.net/wiki/linux:ubuntu:lexmark_x1290](http://web.archive.org/web/20080119224658/http://www.trodrigues.net/wiki/linux:ubuntu:lexmark_x1290) and using the  Z600 series driver from Lexmark.

**Create a directory named lexmark and unpack the driver:**

```
mkdir lexmark
tar -xvzf CJLZ600LE-CUPS-1.0-1.TAR.gz
```

**Extract the driver from the install script:**

```
tail -n +143 z600cups-1.0-1.gz.sh > install.tar.gz
```

**And untar it:**

```
tar -xvzf install.tar.gz
```

This generates 2 drivers (`z600cups-1.0-1.i386.rpm` and `z600llpddk-2.0-1.i386.rpm`) that then should be converted to `.deb` files with `alien` and installed with `dpkg`, but -as the filenames already indicate- the drivers are for 32-bit systems and not for 64-bit systems. Hence the error:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i z600cups_1.0-2_i386.deb 
dpkg: error processing z600cups_1.0-2_i386.deb (--install):
  package architecture (i386) does not match system (amd64)
  Errors were encountered while processing: z600cups_1.0-2_i386.deb
```

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this driver, but you could force the installation by running:

```
sudo dpkg --force-architecture -i z600cups_1.0-2_i386.deb
```

It might still not work, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Here is additional information needed as of 2018 (that is, to install Lexmark X1290 printer on Ubuntu 18.04):

1. The procedure fails at `alien` invocation on a 64-bit system:

   > z600cups-1.0-1.i386.rpm is for architecture i386 ; the package cannot be built on this system

   I could "fool" it by converting to `.tgz` format first, then to `.deb`:

   ```
   sudo alien -t z600cups-1.0-1.i386.rpm
   sudo alien -t z600llpddk-2.0-1.i386.rpm
   sudo alien z600cups-1.0.tgz
   sudo alien z600llpddk-2.0.tgz
   ```

   After which the installation worked:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i z600cups_1.0-2_all.deb 
   sudo dpkg -i z600llpddk_2.0-2_all.deb
   ```
2. The `z600` backend and `rastertoz600` filter need the 32-bit versions of specific libs. I had to install `libstdc++5:i386`, `libcups2:i386` and `libcupsimage2:i386`.
3. After restarting CUPS, I did not have to manually select the PPD file. Model Z600 showed up in the list of Lexmark models.

(Steps taken on Linux Mint 19, based on Ubuntu 18.04. Answer originally posted on Ask Ubuntu, where [this question was duplicated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15537).)